# Prevent Canvas Fingerprinting in DotNetBrowser

Tags: browser-detection, dotnetbrowser

I am trying to get DotNetBrowser to not be identified using Canvas Fingerprinting. You can see details at this website:
https://browserleaks.com/canvas

I've tried turning off the following switches:

```
        ChromiumSwitches.Add("--disable-gpu")
        ChromiumSwitches.Add("--disable-gpu-compositing")
        ChromiumSwitches.Add("--enable-begin-frame-scheduling")
        ChromiumSwitches.Add("--software-rendering-fps=60")
```

Hoping it would give a different fingerprint but still it is identical. There is an excellent Chrome Extension called Canvas Fingerprint Defender that blocks these but I know you can't load extension in DotNetBrowser.

Can anyone think of a way I can use DotNetBrowser while hiding my canvas fingerprint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing the best solution I found was Selenium. It allowed me to load chrome extensions to prevent the fingerprinting.

Answer (score 0):

You can change canvas if inject js code from Canvas Fingerprint Defender
but if you check your browser after using Canvas Fingerprint Defender in page https://ipleak.com/full-report/ You will see metric javascript - disable and this more bad, than good, becouse real canvas - its better, than fake 100% unic canvas.